# Trying to create confluence.kafka library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a Kafka layer for my console apps.

I installed Confluent Kafka  NuGet package.

And in this code

```
private readonly Producer<Null, string> _producer;
private Consumer<Null, string> _consumer;
```

I have error

> Cannot access internal class 'Producer' here
> (class) Confluent.Kafka.Producer<Null,string>  A high level producer with serialization capability.

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In new version of Confluence Kafka package Producer and Consumer are private classes. You must use ProducerBuilder and ConsumerBuilder to create them.

```
        _producerConfig = new ProducerConfig 
        {
            BootstrapServers = host
        };
        _producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(_producerConfig).Build();

        _consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            GroupId = "custom-group",
            BootstrapServers = host
        };
        _consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Null, string>(_consumerConfig).Build();
```